# Formula to set max-width of a div depending on the original dimension of an image within it?

Tags: javascript, html, formula

how can I come up with a formula for the max-width of a div depending on the original width of the image inside it? Below is a sample code from Medium.com which adjusts the logo max-width. The goal is to make the max-width wider as the original image width/height gets smaller. Thank you!

```html
<div class="" style="max-width: 246px;">
  <div class="">
    <div style="padding-bottom: 57.00712589073634%"></div>
    <img class="" src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/492/1*xXpHjKPcR7oYu8NRqGlO8w@2x.jpeg" data-width="1684" data-height="960">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add more code. Have you already tried something? Can you give an actual example of what you're trying to achieve? Either a website or a mockup would suffice.

Comment: @jamie-barker, I tried to come up with a formula on the width-to-height ratio, and multiply it by some constant (e.g. for the sample image that I posted: 960/1684 * C ), where C is the constant. That doesn't work though.

Goal is to arrive to a formula like that of the `<div style="padding-bottom: 57.00712589073634%"></div>`. I was able to get 57% by image Width/Height * 100.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the image max width as well as the div and you may also use  the @media on bootstrap, so that the divs and images will be scalable on different screen resolution such as tablet, desktop and on mobiles.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. We don't use a CSS library though. In our reference site, i.e. Medium, as I try to upload a wider image, the max-width increases. Then if I try to uploaded a wider image than the previous, the max-width increases again. I was thinking that they have some sort of a formula which is handled in javascript after a user uploads the image.